Manim Community: x-axis in radians
I'm trying to change the x-axis in my Manim project to radians, while leaving the y-axis unchanged:
from manim import *
import numpy as np


class RadiansTest(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        axes = Axes(
            x_range=[-10, 10, PI/2],
            y_range=[-10, 10, 1],
            x_length=10,
            y_length=10,
            axis_config={"include_numbers": True,
                         "include_ticks": True}
        )

        graph = axes.plot(np.sin, color=BLUE, x_range=[-10, 10])

        self.play(Create(axes), Create(graph))
        self.wait(2)


I already set the tick distance to pi/2, now I'd like to have the ticks labeled using Latex.
I tried to add this to my code, and although it didn't throw any errors it also didn't change anything:
        tick_labels = {
            -2 * PI: r"$-2\pi$",
            -3 * PI / 2: r"$-\frac{3\pi}{2}$",
            -PI: r"$-\pi$",
            -PI / 2: r"$-\frac{\pi}{2}$",
            0: r"$0$",
            PI / 2: r"$\frac{\pi}{2}$",
            PI: r"$\pi$",
            3 * PI / 2: r"$\frac{3\pi}{2}$",
            2 * PI: r"$2\pi$",
        }

        # Set custom tick labels for the x-axis
        axes.x_axis.set_tick_labels(tick_labels)

Thanks!

You have to add a self.wait() add the end s.t. your changes can appear. But you will see that your approach generates a massive amount of digits.
Here is an approach which is not perfect but shows how it can be done in general:
    axes = Axes(
        x_range=[-10, 10, 3.14/2],
        y_range=[-10, 10, 1],
        x_length=10,
        y_length=10,
        axis_config={"include_numbers": True, "include_ticks": True},
        x_axis_config={
            "include_numbers": False,
        },
    )

    ...

    values_x = [
        (-2 * PI, r"$-2\pi$"),
        (-3 * PI / 2, r"$-\frac{3\pi}{2}$"),
        (-PI, r"$-\pi$"),
        (-PI / 2, r"$-\frac{\pi}{2}$"),
        (0, r"$0$"),
        (PI / 2, r"$\frac{\pi}{2}$"),
        (PI, r"$\pi$"),
        (3 * PI / 2, r"$\frac{3\pi}{2}$"),
        (2 * PI, r"$2\pi$"),
    ]
    x_axis_labels = VGroup()  # Create a group named x_axis_labels
    #   pos.   tex.
    for x_val, x_tex in values_x:
        tex = Tex(x_tex)  # Convert string to tex
        tex.next_to(axes.coords_to_point(x_val, 0), DOWN)  # Put tex on the position
        x_axis_labels.add(tex)  # Add tex in graph
        
    self.add(x_axis_labels)
    self.wait()

I adapted the answer from here: In manim, how do you set the text of the axis labels different to the axis units?

Thanks, but that is not what I need. I'd like to have the ticks to be in Latex symbols like $\pi$ and not 3.14

@haifisch123 Ah I see. I updated my answer.
